# wicket nested ListView (3 times)

Tags: java, html, apache, web, wicket

I'm trying to render a simple collapsible list with apache wicket (6), which looks like this:

```
- A
    - a
        - 0
        - 1
    - b
        - 2
        - ...
- B
    - c
        - ...
    - d
        - ...
```

Currently there are only strings to render. Collapsing is done with JavaScript. The HTML code is structured as ul lists with div labels:

```
<ul>
    <li wicket:id="listOne">
        <div wicket:id="labelOne"></div>

        <li wicket:id="listTwo">
            <div wicket:id="labelTwo"></div>

            <li wicket:id="listThree">
                // actual elements
            </li>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The final output should contain a title and then all sub elements.
The Java code looks like this (one method for each layer):

```
private ListView<String> listItemsLayer0(){
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B");

    return new ListView<String>("layer1List", list){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5656024677354451474L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {
            item.add(new Label("layer0Label", item.getModelObject()));
            item.add(listItemsLayer1());
        }
    };
}
```

The first list is added using an interceptor.
So it works up to two layers. But if I add the third one I get the following execption:

Did not expect a new ContainerElement while another is waiting for its element visit!

How do I solve this? Why can't they be nested above two layers?

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did not expect a new ContainerElement while another is waiting for its element visit!
 at org.nocket.gen.page.visitor.bind.BindingVisitor.visitContainerOpen(BindingVisitor.java:293)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.element.ContainerElement.accept(ContainerElement.java:22)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.visitor.GeneratedBindingVisitor.visitContainerOpen(GeneratedBindingVisitor.java:181)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.element.ContainerElement.accept(ContainerElement.java:22)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:104)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.process(PageProcessor.java:61)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.GeneratedBinding.bind(GeneratedBinding.java:135)
 at de.arvato.crmit.nocket.spring.extension.AbstractNocketSpringPage.bindGeneratedBindings(AbstractNocketSpringPage.java:71)
 at de.arvato.crmit.nocket.spring.extension.AbstractNocketSpringPage.<init>(AbstractNocketSpringPage.java:44)
 at de.arvato.crmit.rio.pages.base.BasePage.<init>(BasePage.java:51)
 at de.arvato.crmit.rio.pages.dokumentencenter.DokumentencenterViewPage.<init>(DokumentencenterViewPage.java:44)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
 at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
 at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:133)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:268)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:166)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:266)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:165)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:861)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Complete stack:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public de.arvato.crmit.rio.pages.dokumentencenter.DokumentencenterViewPage()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
 at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194)
 at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
 at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:133)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:268)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:166)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:266)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:165)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:861)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)

 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
 at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
 at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:133)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:268)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:166)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:266)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:165)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:861)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)

gengui.util.SevereGUIException: On element: <li wicket:id="row"> <span wicket:id="label">the label</span> </li>
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:111)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.traverse(PageProcessor.java:115)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.PageProcessor.process(PageProcessor.java:61)
 at org.nocket.gen.page.GeneratedBinding.bind(GeneratedBinding.java:135)
 at de.arvato.crmit.nocket.spring.extension.AbstractNocketSpringPage.bindGeneratedBindings(AbstractNocketSpringPage.java:71)
 at de.arvato.crmit.nocket.spring.extension.AbstractNocketSpringPage.<init>(AbstractNocketSpringPage.java:44)
 at de.arvato.crmit.rio.pages.base.BasePage.<init>(BasePage.java:51)
 at de.arvato.crmit.rio.pages.dokumentencenter.DokumentencenterViewPage.<init>(DokumentencenterViewPage.java:44)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
 at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
 at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:133)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:268)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:166)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:266)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:165)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:861)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
```

Comment: could you post the full stack trace

Comment: What I forgot to mention: I also use nocket (see GitHub), but that is not used here. Full stack trace added to post.

Comment: Well so at least I fixed the example by creating a sepatate HTML file for the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in this Nocket library. My German is not so good so I cannot understand its purpose.

[Apache Isis](http://isis.apache.org/) also provides Wicket viewer for Naked Objects.

Comment: How do you know its a bug in nocket? And could you create an issue on GitHub then? I now the people developing nocket and it may help them :)

Comment: The last lines in the stacktrace say it is a problem in Nocket. I'd be glad if you prove me wrong.